# ORDER BY is not working for mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a dummy database saved in phpmyadmin.I am trying to sort the data on the basis of column `user_uid`.
Here is some of my database

[image]

The php code that i am using to sort the table is

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';//file contains the variables req to connect to database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM client 
        ORDER BY user_uid;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(($result))
{
    $row = array();
    ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    echo($row['client_name']);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work.What am I doing wrong with the code?

Additional info: `user_uid` is a foreign key and the reference to the user_uid is from another table named users

Comment: You are ordering by cost_per_session and you're asking what's wrong?

Comment: You should have put more effort on debugging your code before posting a question with such a simple answer.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.I had tested the code for user_uid but during editing of the question I mistakenly changed user_uid by cost_per_session.The question is still valid though.It was a question editing fault from my side.

Comment: Ok, `ORDER BY` does *not* "not work". Please describe why you think it doesn't work. What are the results you are getting VS what are the results you are expecting?

Comment: The image that I had posted was the one after i ran my php code.So i was expecting that after the php query was run the data base would be arranged in ascending order.Clearly the database is not in ascending order if it was user_uid having value==1 would have been in the first row

Comment: Are you kiding? The image you have posted in a screenshot from PhpMyAdmin, not the result of your PHP code.

Comment: Put this two lines before the code for creating the `$conn` object in order to see the eventual raised errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` followed by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. And delete that semicolon character (;) after the order by clause. And you don't need all those parenthesis around your vars. And it's `echo $row['client_name'];`.

Comment: Ok just to clarify, you do know that tables in a relational database cannot be "permanently" sorted, right?

Comment: `ORDER BY` just affects the results of that query, it doesn't change the database in any way, and doesn't affect other queries done in the future.

Comment: Ohh...I did not know about that.Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shows only one record. Here is a working example making use of the needed `while` loop to display the `client_name` of each fetched record:

```
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM client 
        ORDER BY user_uid';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['client_name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

I removed all the unneeded parenthesis around the vars and the semicolon at the end of the sql statement.

Good luck.

**Edit 1:** I corrected `$connection` to `$conn`.

**Edit 2:** I implemented the check on the number of rows (`$result->num_rows > 0`) instead of on the `$result` itself (which is always an object of type `mysqli_result` and whos check therefore always returns `true` - even when no records are found).

Comment: See the "Edit 2" and the code, again, Rohan. I'm glad it worked. Ciao.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your code you have written

```
ORDER BY cost_per_session
```

Just change it to

```
ORDER BY user_id
```

you can use ASC or DESC for ascending or descending order.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.I had tested the code for user_uid but during editing of the question I mistakenly changed user_uid by cost_per_session.The question is still valid though.It was a question editing fault from my side